# Spark AR signal value

Tags: facebook, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I am trying to save a scalar signal value for future use as a texture with the Spark AR software.

Basically, using the camera texture on a material is scripted like this:

```
const texture = Textures.get('CameraTexture').signal;
const material = Materials.get('defaultMaterial0');
material.setTexture(texture, {textureSlotName: "diffuseTexture"})
```

It is not clear to me what class is the texture const, but I am guessing this is a [ScalarSignal](https://sparkar.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/reference/classes/reactivemodule.scalarsignal).

That means that it is a stream, not a value. How would I go about snapshotting that value? `lastValue` does not work, and when trying `valueOf()`, I get

> JavaScript error: Exception in native code while calling a function: valueOf() called on a Signal. This probably means that you are trying to perform an arithmetic operation on a signal like +, -, *, etc. Use functions .add, .sub(), etc on the signal instead or .subscribeWithSnapshot() on an EventSource to get the signal's current value on a callback.

And `subscribeWithSnapshot()` is not a function..

If anyone has any idea how I could do this, or the specific reason why I can't, help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Currently in SparkAr is not allowed to save a texture. And I think the data type should be a texture buffer (eventually...)

EDIT: Also, the camera texture signal it's not a scalarSignal but a ShaderSignal.
you can check this:

```
Diagnostics.log(Textures.get('CameraTexture').signal);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information! I don't know if you are in touch with the devs, but It would be really nice to have that feature. Some effect (like movement blur, multi-exposure) are not doable without that..  Do you know if there is a feature request system? Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Are you in the fb group? every announce (and contact with devs...) goes through there: https://www.facebook.com/groups/SparkARcommunity/
And yes, it is a highly requested feature! I read it's on the roadmap, so we just have to wait...

Comment: Nice thanks! My friend posted it the fb group, I guess I'll post further questions there then. Nice to hear that it might be coming! Thanks for being a contributor to this - still small - community!

Comment: Did you see that a signal history appeared? https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/reactivemodule.shadersignalhistory Maybe it can be useful here. Although It seems not working :( here's my question according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63989984/how-to-use-signal-history-in-spark-ar