# How to use signal history in spark ar?

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I'm trying to display the delayed image from the camera:

`material0.setTextureSlot(Shaders.DefaultMaterialTextures.DIFFUSE, cameraTexture0.signal.history(1)[0]);`

but it's not working :( There is only white color on material0.

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Is it working? I it works for me like that `cameraTexture0.signal.history(-5).frame(-1)`, but it doesn't make sense. I can't get values of shader anyway :/